# Require custom enum attribute if enum type has a different custom attribute

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

The title sums it up.  Say I have a custom attribute IsModule defined.  It is used for enum types that I use to load all modules.

I.e assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsModule), true)

Once I have all enums that have that attribute, I iterate each enum and read a different custom attribute ModuleData so that I can insert it into the database.

What I want to do is make this future developer proof by requiring the ModuleData attribute over each enum value IF the IsModule attribute is present on the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no immediate language feature to help. However, three alternate options here:

1. make a Visual Studio (or ReSharper) add-in that will check for this during editing;
2. make an FXCop rule that will check when static code analysis is run;
3. make a unit test that will enumerate all assemblies and make the check.

Note that in case of the unit test (option 3) you need to run it in a way that ensures all assemblies of the program are loaded.

Comment: #1 has my interest peaked.  I could write a whole library of enforcement for developers.  Having never done this before, do you have a good resource to get started?

Comment: @JDBennett Check SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfxcop%5D+custom+rule ;-)

Comment: My fault.   I meant the VS extension or even ReSharper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called module initializer (or module constructor) to scan your module for the enums matching the condition described and throw some exception.

The thing is that while IL supports it, c# itself does not so you need some "help" :)

One possible implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/fody/moduleinit